# Missing or incorrect resource for Google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am fairly new to Google maps so am not sure where to even begin to tackle this problem. It only happens when I hit the "Apply Changes" button but not when I "Run App". Also I dont have a dimen xml in my values folder:

```
06-23 09:15:30.772 2268-2268/com.driptosinha.eataway.eataway E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.locate.store.eataway, PID: 2268
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.locate.store/com.locate.store.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.locate.store:dimen/card_icon_multiline_padding_bottom" (7f060059) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0xc30c21 a=3 r=0x7f060059}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5382)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.driptosinha.eataway.eataway:dimen/card_icon_multiline_padding_bottom" (7f060059) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0xc30c21 a=3 r=0x7f060059}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4178)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2005)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1961)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.aw.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785047@17.7.85 (040308-253824076):35)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fw.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785047@17.7.85 (040308-253824076):12)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785047@17.7.85 (040308-253824076):32)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.dd.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785047@17.7.85 (040308-253824076):2)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.de.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785047@17.7.85 (040308-253824076):11)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.t.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785047@17.7.85 (040308-253824076):29)
        at hp.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785047@17.7.85 (040308-253824076):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zac.zaa(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zaa.onDelegateCreated(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at com.driptosinha.eataway.eataway.ui.MapviewFragment.initGoogleMap(MapviewFragment.java:404)
        at com.driptosinha.eataway.eataway.ui.MapviewFragment.onCreateView(MapviewFragment.java:191)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreat
```

Here is the method that the error is being attributed to:

```
    private void initGoogleMap(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // *** IMPORTANT ***
        // MapView requires that the Bundle you pass contain _ONLY_ MapView SDK
        // objects or sub-Bundles.
        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }
        mapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);

        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        if (geoApiContext == null) {
            geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(getString(R.string.google_api_key)).build();
        }
    }
```

and the onCreateView method where it is being called looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        pickupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapview, container, false);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Find your restaurant");
        mapView = pickupView.findViewById(R.id.list_map);
        ImageView resetButton = pickupView.findViewById(R.id.button_reset_map);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mapviewContext);

        bundle = getArguments();

        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addMarkers();
            }
        });

        getUser();

        initGoogleMap(savedInstanceState);

        return pickupView;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that your app crashes when addMarkers() method executes?

Comment: Based on the stacktrace, it happens even before the addMarkers method is called.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?